# Mapping Instagram Photos

Tags: software-recommendations, instagram

Is there a tool I could use to map Instagram photos that are using a specific tag? I don't necessarily want to show the image on a map, but rather a pin that someone could hover over to see the image. To add context, [I'm developing a game](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/LenKendall/cartegram-find-your-adventure) and would like to include such a feature on the community website.

Comment: Have you looked into the Instagram API?  I know ESRI has examples using Flickr in their JavaScript API.

Comment: http://iirvine.github.io/instamapstagram/index.html

Comment: I'm assuming that's the route I'll need to go. Since I'm not very experienced with code I was hoping there might be an embeddable tool I could drop into my Squarespace site.

Comment: you may want to check the Flickr API. there are some ready to use python scripts how to access and download photos, given a certain query